# Why doesn't the output of the rectifier come out?

Tags: cmos, converter

[image]
Hello, I made a rectifier circuit. I also include a comparator.
I referred to this paper --> An ultra-low-voltage self-powered energy harvesting rectifier with digital switch control.

The circuit consists of two stage. 
first stage, Va signal is working(green color). 
In the next step, however, the voltage drops rapidly.

The output of the vc is not generate. A point connected with a load

Please help me.

Have a nice day. thk.

[image]

Comment: What is the load?

Comment: I made 10u cap and 20K resistor